# Аналог CAPTCHA for Joomla

Tags: joomla, php

Всем участникам форума - здравствуйте. Подскажите, кто уже "сталкивался" с данным вопросом: требуется бесплатный аналог CAPTCHA для CMS Joomla (1.5 (желательно, сайт еще на старом движке), 1.7, 2.5). В интернете много инфы, но может у вас есть подсказка. Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пара капча-подобных защит от ботов для Joomla

- OSOLCaptcha
- EasyCalcCheck PLUS

Comment: Спасибо! Посмотрю.